# Vertical scroll div page divider on page scroll, parallax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a vertical page divider that is used multiple times on a page, it is a div within a div, on the page scroll, I would like the inner div to scroll with the page and then stop when it reaches the end of the parent div.

Any ideas?

Simple HTML

```
<div class="verticalscroll">
  <div class="verticalscroll_bar"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.verticalscroll {
  width: 3px;
  height: 335px;
  background: #D8D8D8;
  margin: 80px auto 0;
}

.verticalscroll_bar {
  width: 3px;
  height: 100px;
  background: pink;
}
```

I appreciate the help!

Comment: can you share screenshot or explain little more what exactly you want

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it... simple really!

Adding this CSS to .verticalscroll_bar

```
  top: 200px;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
```